# How to make CholeskySolve function faster to execute?

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to ask about the solution of [A]{x}={B}. As you know {x} can be obtained by Inverse[A].{B} However, when the dimension of [A] is so large, i.e, dimA=100000, then the inverse function takes so much memory. Then I have decided to implement a function and named as "CholeskySolve" which is below as:

```
CholeskySolve[Amat_, b_] := Module[{b2, L2, U, k, j, i, tot, y},

L2 = Amat;

(*Lower Triangularization*)

For[k = 1, k < Dimensions[L2][[1]] + 1, k++,

L2[[k, k]] = Sqrt[L2[[k, k]]];   


For[i = k + 1, i < Dimensions[L2][[1]] + 1, i++,       

L2[[i, k]] = L2[[i, k]]/L2[[k, k]];

];

   
For[j = k + 1, j < Dimensions[L2][[1]] + 1, j++,        

For[i = j, i < Dimensions[L2][[1]] + 1, i++,     

L2[[i, j]] = L2[[i, j]] - L2[[i, k]]*L2[[j, k]];

];
     
];

];
     
(*Forward Substitution*)
   
b2 = b;

b2[[1, 1]] = b2[[1, 1]]/L2[[1, 1]];   

For[i = 2, i < Dimensions[L2][[1]] + 1, i++,

tot = 0;

For[j = 1, j < i, j++,

tot = tot + L2[[i, j]]*b2[[j, 1]] 

];

b2[[i, 1]] = (b2[[i, 1]] - tot)/L2[[i, i]];

];

(*Backward Substitution*)      

U = Transpose[L2];    

For[i = Dimensions[U][[1]], i > 0, i--,

b2[[i, 1]] = (b2[[i, 1]])/U[[i, i]];      

For[j = 1, j < i, j++,    

b2[[j, 1]] = b2[[j, 1]] - U[[j, i]]*b2[[i, 1]];

];

];

b2

];

ndim = 100;

MatA = RandomMatrix["Symmetric", Real, {1, 5}, {ndim, ndim}];

MatB=RandomReal[{0, 9}, {ndim, 1}];

N[CholeskySolve[MatA, MatB]]
```

Note that RandomMatrix function above has been imported from the link which is https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMatrix/

This CholeskySolve function gets the solution with less memory, however it takes so much time to end, especially for large matrices.

My question is how could the CholeskySolve function above be made faster?

I would appreciate for your help.

Best Regards,

Ahmet

Comment: Have you considered `LinearSolve`?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I have considered LinearSolve, however, it also takes so much computational time and memory. There must be a way to solve 100000x100000 matrix equations, since large finite element modellings can be solved with a fast solver. However, I dont know which way they use.

Comment: I think you are actually interested in a Cholesky solver for sparse matrices. What you wrote down is a Cholesky solver for dense matrices. There is no way that this will work efficiently for matrices of the size you $100000 \times 100000$. Better use `LinearSolve[A, Method->"Cholesky"]`. It should behave a bit better than the standard solver (which is UMFPACK).

Comment: Oh, now I see that you used a dense random matrix as input. Then you can use `LinearSolve[A, Method->"Cholesky"]`, too. But should be orders of magnitude faster than whatever you implement in Mathematica (without compilation) because it uses LAPACK, a highly optimized library.  it will take very long because it is an algorithm of time complexity $O(N^3)$ for a $N \times N$ matrix. I know of no better algorithm for _general_ dense matrices. However, there are of course many specialized algorithms for matrices with special structures (like those that arise from finite elements)...